# Is Google's native Client available for Android's webview and Chrome?

Tags: android, google-nativeclient

Is NaCl and It's Pepper API available on Chrome for Android ? is it available for WebView for Jelly Bean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post dated February 14th, it's not available: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/native-client-discuss/android/native-client-discuss/u3YwbQlMKmY/1MjxER3KxoAJ